# Can you make parameters for a factory function type safe?

Tags: typescript

I'm adding typescript type definitions to my Lua library and I've run in to bit of a block,

in Lua I pass a function to my library which returns a factory

If it was JS it would be something like this:

```
const Factory = Library((params) => {console.log(params.text)});
```

and later you would

```
const instance = Factory({text: "Hello world"});
instance();
```

I have typescript definition for the factory that requires a function arg and returns the correct class type, but I also want type definitions to work for the function's param argument.

```
export function Library(chunk:(params:object)=>void):(params:object)=>instance;
```

(The usecase would be, import the function, load it with my library, and create stuff with the factory, and I'm wondering if it's possible to make the various param objects type safe)

Answer (score 1):

You could add a type parameter for `object`:

```
export function Library<T>(chunk: (params: T) => void): (params: T) => instance
```